# How to get the first items from a list of tuples when each item is also wrapped in another tuple

Tags: python, nested, tuples, extract

So I have this list which is a result of a SELECT request with SQLite:

```
test = [(('over1.5',), 109), 
        (('ht1over0.5',), 101), 
        (('hgover0.5',), 78),
        (('over2.5',), 68), 
        (('agover0.5',), 60)]
```

How do I extract the first items from each tuple so that the expected output would be:

```
['over1.5', 'ht1over0.5', 'hgover0.5', 'over2.5', 'agover0.5']
```

I suppose it has to be done with `re.findall` but I can't figure out how to write the search pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is Python, you can use a list comprehension. You will need to extract the first (only) value of the first element in each `tuple`:

```
res = [i[0][0] for i in test]

# ['over1.5', 'ht1over0.5', 'hgover0.5', 'over2.5', 'agover0.5']
```

Comment: Oh god, I'm so abstract. I was trying i[0] rather than i[0][0] which is actually isolate the first value of the first tuple and not the whole first tuple. I suppose I need some rest hehe. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern:

```
\(\('(.*?)',\),\s(\d+)
```

It starts by matching "`(('`", then creates a `Group 1`, with any number of any characters (this will contain the key), then matching "`',),` " and finally creates a `Group 2` with any number of digits.

This will give you the `key in Group 1` and the `value in Group 2`.

Comment: This way is also good. .*? alone is enough for my situation though, thanks